# Navigation bar link not working properly

Tags: jquery, yii, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

In my yii application, navigation bar link are not active.

I want to selected navigation link (accordion navigation) should be open. Otherwise it is difficult to handle application.

By default, you just need to add `class=”active”` to the sub item, jQuery will automatically add necessary classes to its parents. But this is not working.

Please help me.

Comment: This is not the scope of Yii question. But, can you simply post the code you have tried?

Comment: It's ok. I resolved my problem.